# No me aparecen los atributos en la clase JAVA

Tags: java

no me aparecen los atributos de la clase Car
Cuando pongo car. no me aparece nada.
Creen que pueda ser un tema de pluggins?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así esta la class Car, es como si no la reconociera...

Comment: hola, antes de formular una pregunta primero deberías hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) o ir al [centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help) de esta forma te puedes hacer una idea de como redactar una buena pregunta, y a la ves sea bien recibida por los usuarios de SO.

Answer (score 1):

### El problema

No es ningún problema de plugins hasta donde pude ver. Es problema relacionado a lo que se conoce como *information hiding*.

Tu clase `Main` está a **afuera** del paquete (carpeta) `.vscode`, mientras que tu clase `Car` está **adentro** del paquete `.vscode` y además tiene el modificador de acceso default, que es muy similar (no igual) al modificador `protected`. El cual no permite que una clase sea accedida por otra clase que **no** esté dentro del mismo paquete.

Nota: También noté que no haces uso de `package`, lo cual también es necesario si deseas organizar tu código en varios paquetes.

### La solución

Depende de lo que quieras lograr, pero la más común creo yo sería **hacer la clase `Car` pública**.

Otra solución sería mover todo a un mismo paquete.

**Recomendaciones**

- Prefiere los tipos nativos a las *wrapper classes*. El porqué de esto se trata a detalle en el libro *Effective Java 3rd ed.* del autor *Joshua Bloch*.
- Recomendación meramente personal, estoy de acuerdo si editan esta pregunta y quitan esta recomendación: Si estás aprendiendo a programar, no utilices un IDE al principio porque no vas a entender a profundidad qué es lo que está pasando y por lo mismo, si algo llega a salir mal no vas a saber qué es y probablemente responsabilices a alguien/algo más del error (sea un programa como el IDE, el lenguaje, el compilador, plugins, etc...)

Comment: Hola Benjamín, muchas gracias por la ayuda. Si, estoy aprendiendo a programar y estoy siguiendo un curso de POO en Java en un rato voy a intentar hacer lo que me dijiste y te cuento si me funcionó. Muchas gracias!